# Density of smooth functions in $H^1(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Choose any $k\geq 1$. Do we have

1. $C^k(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ dense in $H^1(\Omega)$?
2. $C^k(\overline{\Omega}):=\{u\in C^k(\Omega):D^\alpha u\in C(\overline{\Omega}),\;\forall 0\leq |\alpha|\leq k \}$ dense in $H^1(\Omega)$?
3. Does the same hold if $k=\infty$ in both questions?

Also, what conditions on $\Omega$ are needed to guarantee such results? Does this hold true for domains with corners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed by convolution techniques is possible to show that for any Lipschitz domain $\Omega$, the space of infinitely smooth and compactly supported  $\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})$ is dense on $H^{1}(\Omega)$. The proof is quite long, see e.g *(1975) Adams Sobolev spaces chp. 3 pp 51.*

In view of the contention
\begin{align}
\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})\subset C^{k}(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega}) \subset H^{1}(\Omega).
\end{align}
applying the closure
\begin{align}
H^1(\Omega)=\overline{\mathcal{C}_0^{\infty}(\bar{\Omega})}^{\|\cdot\|_{H^1(\Omega)}} \subset \overline{ C^{k}(\Omega) \cap C(\bar{\Omega})}^{\|\cdot\|_{H^1(\Omega)}} \subset H^{1}(\Omega).
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't $\overline{C_0^\infty(\overline{\Omega}) }=H^1_0(\Omega) ?$

Comment: No, actually $\overline{C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)} = H^1_0(\Omega)$ of course I assume $\Omega$ is an open domain.